# Who to get gateway IP information into text box

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, ip

Complete nube here. Just learning :)

I've done some research, but couldn't get an answer.

I'm trying to display my gateway IP in a text box. Here's my code (built from snippets):

```
foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation d in f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)

         Gateway_Address.Text = d.Address.ToString();
```

The textbox only show "::"

Now, if I use (copied from another thread):

```
foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation d in f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
            MessageBox.Show(d.Address.ToString());
```

the message box shows the IP. Why are the outputs different?

Comment: Given what you've shown here, the issue is clearly not in the control structure, but elsewhere on your form.

Comment: How many message boxes do you see? You will usually have multiple adapters.

Answer (score 1):

as you are assigning the value to `TextBox` in foreach loop, it can happen that for last item there can be now `IP` atall hence that(Empty IP) will be added to your `TextBox`.

So plese add a check before adding item into `TextBox`

Replace this :

```
Gateway_Address.Text = d.Address.ToString();
```

with following:

```
if(d.Address.ToString().Trim().Length>2)//ignore ::
Gateway_Address.Text = d.Address.ToString();
```

In your second snippet you are displaying each and every `IP` using `MessageBox` hence you are able to see the `IP-Address` which comes inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

```
Gateway_Address.Text += d.Address.ToString() + "\r\n";
```

or

```
var nis = System.Net.NetworkInformation
            .NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .Select(s =>
                string.Format("{0}: {1}", s.Name,
                string.Join(";", s.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(ss => ss.Address.ToString()))));

Gateway_Address.Text = string.Join("\r\n", nis);
```

Comment: Please explain this answer to make it more usable.

Comment: Sometimes, I use string.join + linq to quickly view property values ​​of an object[].